# load data frame into loop of python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

Thank you for checking my question.
I want to use a loop to create three decision trees.
A error message has been showed when i write the code below.

I know it means that data frame has not been load into loop.
what can i do if i want to load data frame into loop?

Thanks

```
"error message: could not convert string to float
"
```

code:

```
"""
NAMES = ['a','b','c']
ExpData  = [data1,data2,data3] # data1,data2,data3 are all dataframe
TatData  = [data1,data2,data3] # data1,data2,data3 are all dataframe
TestData = [data1,data2,data3] # data1,data2,data3 are all dataframe

for i,j,k,q in product(NAMES,ExpData,TatData,TestData):
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4,class_weight="balanced")
    clf = clf.fit(j,k)
    predicted= clf.predict(q)
    dot_file = StringIO()
    tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_file,
                         feature_names=feature_names,
                         class_names=TARGET_NAMES,
                         filled=True, rounded=True)

"""
```

Comment: And which line is it that's throwing the error?  Somewhere, python is expecting a float, and you're passing it a string.  It might be as simple as adding a "float(aaa)" somewhere, where aaa is the variable that's currently a string.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. error has happend for these two lines :clf = clf.fit(j,k) and predicted= clf.predict(q). because i just want to load data frame by index j,k,q but it seems like python can not load the data frame from index

Comment: Generally, it's not wise to blame a programming language for the problems you're having with it.  According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit), the first argument of `fit` will be converted to a float.  What type of data is `j`?  Is it one that can convert?  The same goes for the first argument of [predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict), in your case, `q`.